# Get current Text of editable ComboBox in .NET 4

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

in .NET 3.5 I had a implementation which gets the current edited Text of a comboBox like this:

```
dependencyObject.GetValue(ComboBox.TextProperty);
```

everything worked fine and the value was the edited text on ComboBox.Text-Property. Now we upgraded to .NET 4 and the return value is the old text and not the edited text which is the first strange behavior. But if the previous value of the ComboBox was an item from the ComboBox.ItemsSource, the code above will return the edited value. Currently I have no clue what Microsoft changed on that Property in .NET 4. Has anyone an Idea what could be different now?

Comment: winforms or WPF ? tag it.

Comment: its a WPF application

Comment: That is, you need take the current text in the `ComboBox`?

Comment: yes. I need the current edited text from the editable combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Try use `Text` property like this:

`XAML`

```
<ComboBox Name="MyComboBox" IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" SelectedIndex="0" Width="150" Height="30">
    <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>4</ComboBoxItem>            
    <ComboBoxItem>6</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="GetEditedText" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click" />
```

`Code behind`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    MessageBox.Show(MyComboBox.Text.ToString());
}
```

Or accessed through the template to the `TextBox`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    TextBox input = ((TextBox)MyComboBox.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", MyComboBox));

    MessageBox.Show(input.Text.ToString()); 
}
```